# How to update / increment a column with unique ID based on Reference column

Tags: sql, sap-ase

have a table with some references and dates. I'd like to assign a unique identifier in another column to each reference group. I'm running Sybase ASE 15.7

Sample Data below
Repeating References, with unique dates. I'd like to add a unique identifier in another column for each REFERENCE.

```
REFERENCE   DATES
123 01/01/2020
123 01/02/2020
123 01/03/2020
123 01/04/2020
456 01/01/2020
456 01/02/2020
456 01/03/2020
789 01/01/2020
789 01/02/2020
789 01/03/2020
789 01/04/2020
789 01/05/2020
```

What i'd like to see.

[image: Results with UID column added]

I've been able to update the whole column with an incremental value, but can't work out how to loop through by each reference.
I haven't been able to find any examples of similar issues that would be ASE compatible.
Thanks

Comment: what UPDATE statement have you come up with so far?

Answer (score 1):

**Setup:**

```
create table refs
(reference      int
,dates          date
,uid            varchar(10)     NULL
)
go

set nocount on
go

insert refs (reference,dates) values (123,'01/01/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (123,'01/02/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (123,'01/03/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (123,'01/04/2020')

insert refs (reference,dates) values (456,'01/01/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (456,'01/02/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (456,'01/03/2020')

insert refs (reference,dates) values (789,'01/01/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (789,'01/02/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (789,'01/03/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (789,'01/04/2020')
insert refs (reference,dates) values (789,'01/05/2020')
go
```

**Update:**

The unique/numeric portion of the uid is found by looking for a count of the number of rows with the same `references` value and `dates` less than the current row's `dates` column, and then `+1` for our final value:

```
update refs
set    uid =    convert(varchar(10),reference) + '_' +
                convert(varchar(10), (select    count(*) + 1
                                        from    refs r2
                                        where   r2.reference = r1.reference
                                        and     r2.dates     < r1.dates)
                       )
from   refs r1
go
```

**Results:**

```
select reference,convert(varchar(10),dates,101) as dates, uid
from   refs
order by reference,dates
go

 reference   dates      uid
 ----------- ---------- ----------
         123 01/01/2020 123_1
         123 01/02/2020 123_2
         123 01/03/2020 123_3
         123 01/04/2020 123_4
         456 01/01/2020 456_1
         456 01/02/2020 456_2
         456 01/03/2020 456_3
         789 01/01/2020 789_1
         789 01/02/2020 789_2
         789 01/03/2020 789_3
         789 01/04/2020 789_4
         789 01/05/2020 789_5
```

The above was tested on ASE 15.7 SP138.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (reference + '_' + row_number() over (partition by reference order by date)) as uid
from t;
```

Comment: `row_number()` is not supported in Sybase ASE

Comment: @markp . . . It is very hard to keep track of which versions of Sybase support window functions and which don't.  Do you have a rule for this?

Comment: you mean short of perusing the manuals? :-)   after working on/with ASE for 25 yrs I just ... know ... that windows functions are not supported in ASE (and, yes, I do a quick check of the most current/recent docs just to make sure SAP hasn't sneeked something into the latest release)